# Efficiency of Linq GroupJoin vs. Linq All in Select

Tags: c#, linq

Does Linq use any sorting or other mechanisms to make a group join more efficient so it doesn't have to loop through an entire collection for every unmatched item?

In other words,
Is this:

```
var x = listA.GroupJoin(
listB, a => a.prop,
b => b.prop,
(a, b) => new { a, b })
.Where(!x.b.Any()).Select(x => x.a);
```

more efficient than this:

```
var x = listA.Where(a => listB.All(b => b.prop != a.prop));
```

Comment: You can browse the source code and see for yourself: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1bdae7e7505451ef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the question is about LINQ to Objects, i.e. [`Enumerable.GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535047(v=vs.110).aspx). So yes, the LINQ implementation of the `GroupJoin` (as well as `Join`) is using one of the most efficient general purpose lookup data structures - [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). It can be seen in the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1bdae7e7505451ef) and also is mentioned in the documentation (although not directly) inside the **Remarks** section:

> If comparer is null, the default equality comparer, Default, is used to **hash** and compare keys.

Since hash lookup has O(1) time complexity, the complexity of the join operation is O(N) while in the second case it is O(N * M), so the join is definitely much more efficient.