# C# - Efficiently extracting items from one list in the order of items in another list

Tags: c#, linq

can anyone suggest a performant way of doing this extraction?

.NET Fiddle demo is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hv5eSe), copied below.

The aim is to extract rows from the big list in the order in which the ids appear in the small list.  Handling unfound items would be handy, but might stymie some neat solutions.  However, the simpler case (where all the ids in the small list are guaranteed to be in the big list) is also of interest.  Demo code for the latter case is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ArMzsE).

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

                
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        var biglist = new List<Tuple<int, string>>()
        {
            new Tuple<int, string>(11032035, "GBP"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11025566, "USD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11020456, "USD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11020457, "USD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11030141, "CAD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11026859, "USD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11030142, "CAD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11033667, "USD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11033676, "USD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11031834, "EUR"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11020422, "USD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11020423, "USD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11019982, "EUR"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11029609, "USD"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11000491, "EUR"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11020084, "EUR"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11029141, "LC"),
            new Tuple<int, string>(11025166, "EUR")
        };

        var smalllist = new List<Tuple<int, string, int>>()
        {
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(43, "CAD", 11030141),
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(90, "USD", 11020457),
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(91, "USD", 11029141),
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(102, "USD", 11030142),
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(103, "USD", 11020084),
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(112, "EUR", 11020456),
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(113, "USD", 12345678),
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(114, "USD", 11020423),
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(115, "USD", 11025566),
            new Tuple<int, string, int>(129, "CAD", 11000491)
        };
    
    
        List<Tuple<int, string>> orderedextract = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < smalllist.Count; i++)
        {
            Tuple<int, string> found = biglist.Where(x => x.Item1 == smalllist[i].Item3).
                Select(x => new Tuple<int, string>(x.Item1, x.Item2)).FirstOrDefault();
        
            if (found == null)
            {
                found = new Tuple<int, string>(smalllist[i].Item3, "not found");
            }
        
            orderedextract.Add(found);
        }
    
        foreach (Tuple<int, string> pair in orderedextract)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pair.Item1.ToString() + " " + pair.Item2);
        }
    }
}
```

> ```
> 11030141 CAD
> 11020457 USD
> 11029141 LC
> 11030142 CAD
> 11020084 EUR
> 11020456 USD
> 12345678 not found
> 11020423 USD
> 11025566 USD
> 11000491 EUR
> ```

Comment: `for` loop with `Where`? can't you umm, use `Where` combined with the `Any`?

Comment: @BagusTesa Will that keep the order?  Will check it out.  I think there must be a single pass approach which would be really fast.  The lists in my application are huge and the repeated Where calls make it very slow.

Comment: well, pairing `for` and `Where` would at least two passes one the `for` and the `Where` might uses quickselect down the line (haven't check the code). but to be honest, i would put readability above speed by using all [tag:linq] not using it half heartedly like this - just use pure `for` if you need speed on application side. for the order, you can use `OrderBy` and `IndexOf`.

Comment: also, is this involve a database? if so, it would be far better to have everything translated into sql query by [tag:linq]'s `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the NewExtract method, an optimized approach is used to improve the performance. First, the bigList is transformed into a dictionary where the numbers (Item1) from bigList become the keys, and the corresponding strings (Item2) become the values in the dictionary.

Then, the smallList is looped through. For each number (Item3) in the smallList, the code checks if this number exists as a key in the bigListDictionary. If it does, the associated string value is retrieved from the dictionary. If the number is not found in the dictionary, it adds a default value of "NOT FOUND". These key-value pairs (or "Tuples") are then added to the orderedList.

By using a dictionary, the code significantly speeds up the search process. Dictionaries allow for fast lookups based on keys, which makes finding values associated with specific keys much quicker compared to searching through a list linearly. This optimized approach improves the efficiency of the NewExtract method.

In the given code example, several modifications have been made to enhance its scalability and ease of testing.

.NET-Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hvzqOu

Code:

```
private static void NewExtract() 
{
    Dictionary<int, string> bigListDictionary = bigList.ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2);
    orderedList = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < smallList.Count; i++)
    {
        int key = smallList[i].Item3;
        string value;

        if (bigListDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            orderedList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(key, value));
        }
        else
        {
            orderedList.Add(new Tuple<int, string>(key, "NOT FOUND"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. Dictionary lookup is so much faster than Where().Select.  My timing dropped from 15 seconds to practically instant. I will have to check out Oliver's answer before accepting to be fair.

Comment: Accessing a value in a C# Dictionary is O(1) constant time because it can directly access the value using its key. This means the access time remains constant regardless of the Dictionary's size, making it very fast.

Answer (score 4):

You can [perform a left outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) as explained in the link. I am keeping the C# LINQ syntax, as it is easier for joins.

```cs
var ordered =
    from a in smalllist
    join b in biglist on a.Item3 equals b.Item1 into gj
    from c in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select (id: a.Item3, currency: c?.Item2 ?? "not found");

foreach (var item in ordered) { 
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

According to this answer [Efficiency of Linq GroupJoin vs. Linq All in Select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39209015/880990) the group join uses a hash table (as does `Dictionary<K,V>`) and is **very efficient**.

Note that I am using C#'s new [Value Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) for the result. We can use them for the input lists as well to simplify the code. It is also more memory efficient, as we don't need to create objects on the heap.

```cs
var biglist = new List<(int id, string currency)>() {
    (11032035, "GBP"),
    (11025566, "USD"),
    ...
    (11025166, "EUR")
};

var smalllist = new List<(int number, string currency, int id)>() {
    (43, "CAD", 11030141),
    (90, "USD", 11020457),
    ...
    (129, "CAD", 11000491)
};
```

Since the value tuples are not nullable, we must drop the null-conditional operator `?.` in the select-statement:

```cs
select (id: a.Item3, currency: c.Item2 ?? "not found");
```

And we can use named tuple items:

```cs
var ordered =
    from a in smalllist
    join b in biglist on a.id equals b.id into gj
    from c in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select (a.id, currency: c.currency ?? "not found");
```

Comment: Good code, good explanation